# How to detect element resize on IE11; alternative for element.onresize event?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, internet-explorer-11

Internet Explorer 11 no longer supports the [`onresize` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536959) on arbitrary DOM elements, which works fine on IE < 11. Is there any alternative that works on the new Edge Doctype?

I can detect when the style attribute has changed via a [`MutationObserver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn265034), but with this I can't detect size changes originated elsewhere (CSS pseudo classes e.g. :hover, CSS animations, etc.)

Any idea on how this can be achieved on Internet Explorer 11?

Comment: Is this IE-only code? If not, what are you currently doing for the other browsers? Just trying to get an idea of whether there is some other way to approach the problem.

Comment: @DaveMethvin indeed this is IE-only code. On other browsers I'm using underflow/overflow events. You can check out this [library](https://github.com/sdecima/javascript-detect-element-resize) for more info. That's where I want to put full IE11 support and hence this question.

Answer (score 2):

IE11 doesn't support it anymore. You need to use the polyfill from

https://github.com/marcj/css-element-queries

It has a class `ResizeSensor` which works with all browsers.

Comment: That polyfill is not super well documented as to how it works, so this fiddle might help as a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sstur/w1yoeg99/